# Update document with specified key value, otherwise insert new document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

This is using the MongoDB Java driver. I have a document:

`BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", playername).append("posX", xpos)
                        .append("posY", ypos);
                        collection.insert(doc);`

where `xpos` and `ypos` are just integers and `playername` is just a string. Id like to perform an upsert but not sure of the proper syntax to do it. Basically, if a document exists that has the same `playername` value, update that documents `posX` and `posY` values. Otherwise, if a document with the specified `playername` does not exist, insert a new document with those fields.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You're looking for "upsert".

Answer (score 0):

This is a link that might help: http://techidiocy.com/upsert-mongodb-java-example/